# Restore database to old data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL server. I have a table named task and a column in it which is taskname. Now if someone updates the taskname from "ABC" to "DEF" I don't want that  to be updated I want it to stay ABC in taskname column. I hope my issue is clear to all.Can someone guide me how can I do this.

Comment: You can handle it in code on a higher layer, like in a stored procedure or repository or model etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a triggerthat prevents this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_name_me
ON tbl_name
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM INSERTED I
   JOIN DELETED D ON D.PK = I.PK AND ISNULL(D.name,I.name+'.') <> ISNULL(I.name,D.name+'.')
)
RAISERROR('Changes to the TABLENAME tbl_name are NOT allowed', 16,1);
GO
```

This creates an event that automatically is activated when an update statement is produced.

Comment: can you explain what is D.PK I.PK and D.name I.name

Comment: PK is the primary key of your table- And name is your taskname.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new table which has a "TaskName" column as Primary key.
- Insert your current TaskName's to this table.
- Define your current "TaskName" column as Foreign Key referring to the new table. You can define Cascade rules as you wish.